# Masked links with square brackets aren't rendered in comment Markdown

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

The usual referencing style for the C++ standard is [[basic.lookup.elab] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2) (with some variations).
To produce this, you need two write `[[basic.lookup.elab] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2)`.

This works just fine in Q&A Markdown, but it's broken in comment markdown.
It simply displays the markdown source as if it wasn't a masked link.

Comment: [[basic.lookup.elab] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not a [supported form of Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), on SO.

In Q&A, these formats are available:

```
Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
Here's a reference-style link to [Google][1].
Here's a very readable link to [Yahoo!][yahoo].

  [1]: http://www.google.com/
  [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
```

(Source: [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Comments only support the first (inline) format.

Your nested brackets simply break the MD parser for comments, as it's invalid MD.
If you want to include those brackets in your link in comments, you need to escape the brackets with a backslash:

```
[\[basic.lookup.elab\] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2)
```

Comment: [\[testing\]](https://www.google.com). Yeap, you can escape the brackets in comments: `[\[testing\]](https://www.google.com)`